# Sub-arrays can't be changed individually when created at the same time

Tags: python, arrays, sub-array

I created an array with two sub-arrays containing zeros:

```py
a=[[0]*3]*2
```

This looks like so:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I try to modify the first value of the first sub-array like this:

```py
a[0][0] = 1
```

Then the array looks like this:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

The second sub-array was changed as well. If i create the sub-arrays individually by writing

```py
a=[0]*2
a[0]=[0]*3
a[1]=[0]*3
```

and then execute the same command to modify the first value, the result looks like this:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Why does the array behave differently in these cases and is there a way to change values of sub-arrays when initializing them together?

Comment: this will most likely answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8056130/10875953

Comment: `a = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(2)]`

Comment: BTW, these are *lists* not arrays, in Python 'array' generally implies a `numpy` array (or even an `array.array`,  but that's more esoteric)

Comment: So the reason is because the sub-arrays (or sub lists, as it were) here are actually the same object?

Comment: Yes - the `*` operator on a list will copy the references in the multiplied list. The docs describe it as "equivalent to adding [the list] to itself n times" and note this common problem in footnote 2 here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations